# Wrap CTE inside another Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to wrap a `CTE` inside of another `Select` statement?

Here is my `CTE`:

```
WITH IRS AS

(SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, WTHD_ENTITY,  WTHD_TYPE, WTHD_CLASS 
FROM PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD
WHERE WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'  ) ,

PA AS
(SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, WTHD_ENTITY,  WTHD_TYPE, WTHD_CLASS
FROM PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD
WHERE WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'  )

SELECT IRS_WTHD.BUSINESS_UNIT, IRS_WTHD.VOUCHER_ID, IRS_WTHD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
--COLUMN 1 TO BE USED IN MAIN QUERY:
CASE WHEN PA_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA' THEN 'PA'
     WHEN IRS_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_TYPE = '1099N' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS = '01' THEN 'IRS'
     WHEN IRS_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_TYPE = '1099'
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS = '07'  THEN 'IRS'
     ELSE ''
     END , 
--COLUMN 2 TO BE USED IN MAIN QUERY:
CASE WHEN PA_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA' THEN CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS, '0', ' ')), ' ','0') AS VARCHAR)
     WHEN IRS_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_TYPE = '1099N' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS = '01' THEN 'MISC' + CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') AS VARCHAR)
     WHEN IRS_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS' 
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_TYPE = '1099'
      AND IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS = '07'  THEN 'MISC7'
     WHEN PA_WTHD.WTHD_ENTITY = '' THEN ''
     ELSE 'MISC' + CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(IRS_WTHD.WTHD_CLASS, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') AS VARCHAR)
     END

FROM IRS IRS_WTHD
LEFT JOIN PA PA_WTHD ON PA_WTHD.BUSINESS_UNIT = IRS_WTHD.BUSINESS_UNIT AND PA_WTHD.VOUCHER_ID = IRS_WTHD.VOUCHER_ID AND PA_WTHD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = IRS_WTHD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
```

I would like to wrap the above `CTE` inside of this main SQL Select statement below and output the two `CASE` statement columns above into the final `SELECT` statement below while joining on `BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, and VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` fields from the `PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD` table :

```
--Main Select Statement:
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                                                 
THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, B.QTY_VCHR, A.UNIT_PRICE, A.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, A.DESCR, A.PO_ID, A.LINE_NBR,
A.SCHED_NBR, B.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM, A.DESCR254_MIXED, '','', 
F.OR_ENTITY + '.' + F.OR_LOCATION + '.' + CASE WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL IN ('90000', '90032', '90059') AND H.DEPTID = '741' THEN H.COST_CENTER
                                                       WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = '90000' AND H.DEPTID = '956' THEN H.COST_CENTER
                                                       WHEN B.DEPTID IN ('882', '883', '884', '885', '886', '803' , '887', '888') THEN '676'
                                                       ELSE '000' END  
+ '.' + B.ACCOUNT + '.' + ISNULL(G.ORACLE_PROJECT_CODE,'000000000.') + ISNULL(NULLIF(B.AFFILIATE, ''), '00000.') + '.000000.' + '000000' ,'', C.ACCOUNTING_DT, '',
 '','','', ISNULL(D.WTHD_ENTITY,''), '', '', '', A.SALETX_AMT 
                                                                                                 
FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
WHERE C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
 AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
 AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
 AND C.ENTRY_STATUS <> 'X'
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Is this possible, or is there an alternate way of avoiding using the CTE? I am using the CTE because I need to be able to run `Case` statements across multiple rows and possibly return data on other rows.

Comment: CTEs can only go at the *start* your your statement, and must all be defined prior to the final `SELECT`/DML statement. Also, those are `CASE` **expressions**, not `Case` (`Switch`) statements; T-SQL does not support the latter.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean by "wrap the above query", but an option could be to create a view of the query with the CTE and JOIN the view into your main query.  Be mindful of performance, though.

Comment: I want to output the result of the CASE statements in the CTE into the Main Select statement. I used a CTE because I needed to evaluate data for a VOUCHER_ID on multiple rows.

Comment: Have you tried defining a query that joins IRS and PA as a CTE and referencing the CTE in the main query?